# How can I add a default image (or images) to my posts?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-fields

I am currently making a Wordpress plugin and I nearly have it working. It is a custom post type with default values, columns and custom fields (Advance Custom Fields).

```
function newplugin_install() {

$new_post = array( 
    'post_title' =>     'One Once Un Single',
    'post_content' =>   '(FIRST). Lorem ipsum dolor set elit...',
    'post_status' =>    'publish',
    'post_type' =>      'exhibitor'
    // INSERT default.png here somehow
);


//SAVE THE POST
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);


}
```

I would like to add a default image based on the featured image or based on an ACF image type. I have no idea where to start.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1- First if you need to insert the post

Note: if you know the post id and you don't need to inset new one, you can skip the second step

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    =>  $title,
    'post_content'  =>  $outputValue,
    'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
    'tags_input'    =>   $tags_keywords,
    'post_status'   =>  'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type' =>  'post'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );

    //SAVE THE POST
  $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

2- Second inserting images

// code for: if you want to insert image from URL

```
if(isset($_POST['the_img_link']) && $_POST['the_img_link'] != ''){
    $image_url = $_POST['the_img_link'];
    basename($image_url);
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($image_url);
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])){
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    }else{
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    }
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $pid );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    set_post_thumbnail( $pid, $attach_id );
}else{
    // $other_attach_id is any previous added attached image
    // you want it to be a default image
    set_post_thumbnail( $pid, $other_attach_id )
}
```

// code for: if you want to insert image your pc

```
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $pid );
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
        set_post_thumbnail( $pid, $attach_id );
    }
}else{
    // $other_attach_id is any previous added attached image
    // you want it to be a default image
    set_post_thumbnail( $pid, $other_attach_id )
}
```

Comment: it's better to do that in a custom template page , you can follow that tutorial [Wordpress Codex Page_Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

Comment: So should this insert an image into my example custom post types? Where is your code getting a default image from?

Comment: Ye this will add Feature Image for your post, I edit the last block of code so it will work well with you, because i was doing some edits in my Functions.php file , so you don't need to edit that file

Comment: I have added your code but it does not seem to do anything. I still do not see where the default files are coming from. I have entered some default content but I cannot figure out how to see my **default.png** file.

Comment: $_POST['the_img_link'] will not work for me I am not inserting content via some form. I am inserting content (my image) upon installation of my custom-post-type plugin.

Comment: After the end of `if($_FILES){...}`
or the end of `if(isset($_POST['the_img_link']) && $_POST['the_img_link'] != ''){...}`
you can add `else{set_post_thumbnail( $pid, $attach_id )}`
Note that $pid is your post ID, and $attach_id is the id of any previous added attach image

Comment: I've edited the code in my post slightly adding `else{...}` @scottgemmell